# Find joint probability and calculate $\mathbb{E}(X)$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, expectation, poisson-distribution

Consider the number of children in a family (poisson-distributed with parameter $\lambda$).

Suppose each child is equally likely to be male or female.

Let $X$ be the number of male children and let $Y$ be the number of female children.

$a)$ Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

$b)$Find two different ways to calculate $\mathbb{E}$$(X)$.

**Idea**:

$a)$ So  I want to have $P(X=x,Y=y)$, right? I know, that the probability for $x+y$ children is $e^{-\lambda} \cdot \frac{\lambda^{x+y}}{(x+y)!}$, because the number of children in a  family is poisson distributed, right? Hm, if this right it is intuitively clear that the probability for $x$ male children and $y$ female children is: $\binom{x+y}{x} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{x+y}$. If this is correct I have to find a way to combine this. 
If this isn't correct, please tell me how I can calculate the joint distribution. Second question: $ X $ and $Y$  are independent if $P$($X \cap Y$)=$P$($X$)$P$($Y$), but how I can find these terms?

b) Obviously one way has to be $a)$. So we have to use $a)$ somehow.
My idea for the second way is to Wald's equation. I hope this is right and I hope that you can help me to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Comment: You are assuming the same $\lambda$ For $X$ and $Y$, however the $\lambda$ could be different

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track for the first one. The correct way to combine them is multiplication. We have $$ P(X=n,Y=m) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n+m}}{(n+m)!}\frac{1}{2^{n+m}}{n+m\choose m}.$$

As an alternative way to compute $E(X)$ is to note that by symmetry $E(X) = E(Y)$ so we have $$2E(X) = E(X+Y)=E(N) =\lambda.$$

Comment: According to Teh Rod, we are assuming $\lambda$  for $X$ and $Y$. He said that $\lambda$ could be different. What can we do now?  Thanks for a third way to calculate $E(X)$.  Any idea how to calculate $E(X)$ with my two ways?

Comment: When you assume that conditional on the number of children, the probability of boy/girl is 50-50 (i.e., the number of boys/girls is $Bin(n,1/2)$) you are assuming the birth rate $\lambda$  is the same for both boys and girls. For your first way, when you sum the expression I wrote down over $m,$ you will get that $P(X=n)$ is such that $X$ is a Poisson with mean $\lambda/2.$ Wald's equation will work too if you frame the problem up as a random sum in the right way. (It will look a lot like my alternative way.)

Comment: I solved this task except the Wald-part. So Wald says that we need $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ independent. and we need a random variables $N$, which is independent to $X_i$. Then the following equality holds: $E(X_1)E(N) = E(X_1 + .... + X_N)$. if $E(X_1)$ is $1/2$ , $E(N) = \lambda$ and $E(X_1 + .... + X_N)$ = E(X) then it would be fine. But I dont see why.

Comment: We can write $X_i=1$ if child $i$ is a male and $0$ if child $i$ is female and write the total number of children as $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i.$ Then $E(X_i) = 1/2$ and $E(N)=\lambda.$